# C++ Naming conventions for disposble return pointer function

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I have a function that returns a pointer that should be destroyed by the caller. is there any convention for hinting such thing in the function name?

Comment: You can return a smart pointer instead of raw pointer.

Comment: No there is no such convention as there is no reason to return such pointer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl why don't you post this as an answer so I could give you a vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to such a function should be the first thing you do. Second should be to change it to return a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` rather than a raw pointer. Trying to "hint" things in function names is *never* going to be a good option - the compiler won't enforce it. 
Use the type system.